# How to deploy and sync a prototype Clojurescript app with Git?

Tags: git, clojure, clojurescript

I've been writing a Clojurescript app using figwheel. I intermittently push my code to a Git repository. 
I'd like people to be able to try the latest version I push, in their browser.

I've used AWS EC2 instances to host javascript apps before, but I had to manually `cp` my code every time I wanted to update them.

Is there a convenient way to deploy and sync a cljs browser app with Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github Pages is very convenient for hosting pages, as it serves things out of a branch `gh-pages` of your repo.

http(s)://username.github.io/projectname

I like to use a deploy.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd $(dirname $0)
lein do clean, cljsbuild once min
cd resources/public
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub Pages"
git push --force --quiet "git@github.com:timothypratley/pirates.git" master:gh-pages
rm -fr resources/public/.git
```

You can also nominate a directory:
https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing

Firebase and Heroku are good if you need more features.

Comment: Quick question: from the script it looks like you are pushing only the folder containing the compiled js, css files, and index.html; is that true? And does this mean I need a separate repo from the one I normally push to?

Comment: Yes it only pushes the compiled assets to the `gh-pages` branch. No you do not need a separate repo... the gh-pages branch contains only the things you want to publish. I think the folder approach is simpler, it only just got released but seems pretty cool.